# Login timeout expired error when connecting to a local sql server using pyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

when trying to connecnt to my local sql server i keep on getting the following error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

this is my code:

```
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;port=32782;DATABASE=db;UID=db;PWD=db;Trusted_Connection=yes')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db.tt_content LIMIT 3')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Note: this sql server inside a ddev container

Note2: i tried `SERVER=127.0.0.1,32782` and got the same result

Comment: I don't know what a "ddev container" is, but it may well have its own IP address. If so, then you'd have to use that one instead of localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: i don't think so as i can connect to the DB with another tool on the same IP and port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turnsout that my database is a mariaDB so i used mysql.connector instead and it connected